# Delete where Date = DD.MM.YYYY on table with 20m records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

at the moment I am using the statement:

```
delete
from tbl_name
where trunc(tbl_name.Timestamp) = to_date('06.09.2013','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

But this takes very very long. 
Is there a way to speed things up?

Thank you

Comment: where trunc(tbl_name.Timestamp) = to_date('06.09.2013','DD/MM/YYYY') will kill you due to TRUNC. Look for a better way like extract function to get the dates and delete. I would go for loading the PK in separate table using the conditions and then delete joining the temp table with PK. Also look at your UNDO.

Comment: Approx. how many of the 20m records are being deleted?

Comment: are you sure of your to_date format? It seems odd to me that you display the date with dots and specify the format with forward slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is certainly a big table. Otherwise I see no point in a statement like yours taking very long.

Then there are two possibilities:

1) The delete statement affects many, many records.

Then it's only natural for the statement to take long. The whole table will have to be scanned (full table scan). You could only speed this up by parallelizing the statement:

```
delete /*+parallel(tbl_name,4)*/ from tbl_name ...
```

2) The delete statement affects a rather small percentage of the records in the table.

Then it would be advisable for Oracle to use an index. As you are asking only for the date portion of the timestamp column, you would create a function index:

```
create index index_name on tbl_name( trunc(the_timestamp) );
```

Once there is that index available on the table, Oracle can use it to find the desired records on selects, updates and deletes based on trunc(the_timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

Use a between value in right side instead of using trunc on left side.

```
delete from tbl_name
where tbl_name.Timestamp between to_date('06.09.2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
and  to_date('06.09.2013 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: And what about a row that has the `tbl_name.Timestamp` value as  `'06.09.2013 23:59:59.100'` - 1 tenth of a second later than 23:59:59? There is almost a whole second left there... (What if all the rows are in _that_ second?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a better condition instead of the `trunc`, especially if you have an index on the tbl_name.Timestamp field:

```
    tbl_name.Timestamp >= to_date('06.09.2013','DD/MM/YYYY') --inclusive
AND tbl_name.Timestamp <  to_date('07.09.2013','DD/MM/YYYY') --exclusive
```

I assumed you don't have a function index on trunc(tbl_name.Timestamp), in which case that *should* provide better performance.

<sub>Based on my previous experience, (which is **not backed up by straight facts or theory**, or even more, [the facts are against this approach](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022)): You could break it up into smaller bunches</sub>

```
delete
from tbl_name
where 
  id in (select id from tbl_name 
  and trunc(tbl_name.Timestamp) = to_date('06.09.2013','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  and rownum<10000); -- tune this to your liking
```

And repeat this. Don't forget to commit in between... This helped me, we were using SNAPSHOT isolation level.

Comment: Doing it in many small transactions will actually take longer than with one big transaction. Changing the condition to make use of an index on the `timestamp` might make a bigger difference if not too many rows are updated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name on 10gR2, with some load from other sessions, breaking up similar queries did help. Though I think that server was not set up the best way it could have been set up...

Comment: Using many small transactions *increases* the work Oracle has to do. You might want to read this: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't question anyone's expertise, and do agree with the article, and the facts backing it up. But should I _deny and forget_ what I experienced? Should I lie to myself too, and make it unhappened? Should I not try to help people seemingly in the same boots with that? Sure, I'm not in possession of all the relevant background information that would explain why I saw what I saw, but just because of that I can not be sure the OP is not facing a similar issue than I did (I do remember this was a recurring issue, but it does not help that it was years back.)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that since you are referring to the `tbl_name.Timestamp` column, then I am sure there must be a primary key also associated with it. In case the primary key is a numeric value, you could use that index in your delete statement, kind of like:

> delete from tbl_name where **tbl_name.ID** between **LOWER_ID_VALUE** AND **UPPER_ID_VALUE**

Note: The LOWER_ID_VALUE and UPPER_ID_VALUE are inclusive in nature, meaning records of those two IDs will also be deleted.

ppeterka 66's  idea of breaking down the delete using rownum isn't feasible. Take a look at [http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689)

> Assuming you are running Oracle, when the DELETE command is issued, the deleted rows are stored in the rollback segments, so, if required, changes can be undone. So there is an image of the rows in rollback which are currently not present in the table. Now all the rollback blocks are written to the redo log files too. So you have the data blocks with the table (without the deleted rows, of course) and the rollback blocks with the old image both producing redo, which accounts for additional archive logs.

Hence, its better to go for it in a single step rather than breaking it down into multiple transactions and doing it.

Comment: If the column is a timestamp I'd find it highly *unlikely* that it would have a primary key constraint.